# Is there a Jenkins Radiator plug-in that can display jobs from different CloudBees Folders?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, directory, cloudbees

Does anyone know if there is a Radiator view plug-in that will display jobs from different Folders?

I have several streams of testing managed using Folders.  Within each of these streams I have an environment check job to ensure the test environment is in a fit state.  I want to create a single radiator view showing me the state of all environments.

thanks

Glenn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well [as of Jenkins 1.512](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/757) you can include jobs in subfolders in a regular *List View*. For the Radiator View plugin to also support jobs in subfolders it would very likely need to be patched as well.